# How to share data between soap header and web service methods in apache cxf

Tags: java, apache, soap, cxf

I have a SOAP web service developed using Apache CXF. The web service will be passed a parameter in the SOAP header that I must pass to the web service method. How can I obtain this parameter in the web service method?
For eg. my web service method is getCustomerByName(String name). 
The request SOAP header will have a parameter, authentication=ticket. How can I get this value (ticket) inside the method.
I tried Interceptors - they allow to get the Header details but where do I store this and get it in the method body. IS there a shared context or a property that I can set?

Answer (score 4):

JAX-WS has a WebServiceContext object that can be injected via an @Resource annotation.   From the context, you should be able to get anything that you set into the message in an interceptor.

OR

You could use PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage() to get CXF's current message and retrieve anything you need.

OR

You could modify the method to something like:  getCustomerByName(@WebParam(header = true) String auth, String name)  to have CXF pass the header in.

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel. I tried both the WebServiceContext and PhaseInterceptorChain and was able to read the headers. Are both the above methods threadsafe? I mean each request will contain a different ticket value that I want to read. I guess, it is, as each request will contain its own message. am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked:

```
`Message message = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage();

List<Header> headers = CastUtils.cast((List<?>) message.get(Header.HEADER_LIST));

for(Header hd : headers){
   if (hd!=null){
    //do dom parsing
    Element e = (Element)hd.getObject();
    e.getTextContent());
    }
}`
```